# How can i validate django field with either of two validators?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, orm

Here is the code,
I want **ip_address** to satisfy either of **validate_fqdn** or **validate_ipv4_address**.

```
import re
def validate_fqdn(value):
    
    pattern = re.compile(r'^[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\.?[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+$')
    if not pattern.match(value):
        raise ValidationError('Provided fqdn is not valid')
    return value

class KSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    ip_address = serializers.CharField(max_length = 100, validators = [validate_fqdn, validate_ipv4_address])
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

A new validator will do:

```py
def validate_fqdn_or_ipv4_address(value):
    try:
        return validate_fqdn(value)
    except:
        return validate_ipv4_address(value)
```